# How to keep using home folder for electron in MAS build?

Tags: electron, electron-builder

I have an app in electron that needs to stored some files in the user directory `/Users/myuser`.
When developing the app I used

```
const userHome = require('user-home');
```

For Windows and Mac (DMG target) and everything was great!

Now I'm doing MAS build, but what is happening is that the MAS target, once installed in the machine, is not using the userHome as `/Users/myuser`, instead it's using `/Users/myuser/Library/Containers/myapp/Data`

And the thing is that I need a more user friendly directory so the user can interact with those files/folders.

Is there a way I can do this for cross platform/targets? PD: I'm using electron-builder for the build.

Comment: One thing worth considering is to allow the user to launch the Finder at your app's "home" directory from within the application. That way, your users would have an intuitive way of finding their app data and you don't have to try to circumvent Apple's containerisation. Take a look at Electron's [`shell`](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/api/shell) module.

Comment: Yes, we are doing that... But it is not user friendly to do that. We want to know where the data is and how to access to that using or not our app. Is like Google Drive, you can see your files in your home folder. Also in case they uninstall the app they should be able to keep the data